# Email Aliases in Microsoft Graph API

Tags: email, graph, microsoft-graph-api, basic-authentication

I have 15 email aliases currently using IMAP with basic authentication. How do I move these to Microsoft Graph. Do I need to create an app for each email alias for authentication?

Comment: Are all these email aliases going into the same mailbox? If so why do you need to access it 15 times?

If they are individual mailboxes, then yes, you will need to connect to them with each account and consent the individual Azure AD application access to it.

Comment: Yes. These email aliases are on the same mailbox. Can you confirm if I will need an app registration per mailbox and not per alias?.

Answer (score 0):

you will be able to do an app registration and have the user of the mailbox consent the application access to their mailbox using Mail.Read permissions. 
If the alias is just sending email into the inbox of that mailbox, then the application will have access to them.

Comment: I have a use case where I have 15 email aliases on a mailbox. During the app authentication, will it ask for which email aliases that I can give access to. If so, can I give access to only two email aliases. Will I be able to get a different access token only for those two email aliases?. Or the access and refresh token is generated per mailbox.

Comment: The app will auth and consent access to each mailbox. The app will be given one access token after it has made all its consents.